# mongorestore hangs while restoring fs.chunks

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongodump, mongorestore

I am trying to upgrade from the mongodb sandbox option onto a shared cluster, and to keep my current data I have to do a mongodump and mongorestore to migrate the old data onto the new database.

This is what I put in the command line.

```
mongorestore -h url:host -d heroku_zc -u heroku_zc -p 470grupv030prq5uj0fm mongo-dump-dir/heroku_9r
```

It seems to all go fine and restores all the data entries, but while uploading the file chunks it hangs part way through. Sometimes 5% of the ay through sometimes 20% of the way through sometimes 50%.

As I say, when I look at the new database, all the rows are there correctly, and only the actual data files are missing.

This is what happens in the terminal, it doesn't give an error it just stops.

```
2017-02-09T15:45:20.509+0100    [#.......................]  heroku_z25kbwmc.fs.chunks  15.8 MB/299.6 MB  (5.3%)
2017-02-09T15:45:23.509+0100    [#.......................]  heroku_z25kbwmc.fs.chunks  15.8 MB/299.6 MB  (5.3%)
2017-02-09T15:45:26.510+0100    [#.......................]  heroku_z25kbwmc.fs.chunks  15.8 MB/299.6 MB  (5.3%)
```

Both db's are created from heroku as addons to my parse server.

EDIT: I also don't know if this is a problem, the local system database says 2.03GB. I don't understand how this can be, as the total database size is only 500mb

[image]

Comment: What is your sharded cluster configurations (bumber of shards/number of replicaset? ) Which engine are you using (WiredTiger/MMapv1...?) and what level of compression (none/snappy/zlib?)

Comment: What does db.currentOp() show while you're trying to restore your dump and it hangs?